# In a foreach loop and write a file

Tags: php, json, image, for-loop, each

I currently have this code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://openstates.org/api/v1/legislators/?active=true&state=fl&&chamber=upper&apikey=ba09e678541e4b6ea28348c4517a6d50');
$obj = json_decode($json);


foreach($obj as $index => $user) 
    echo $user->photo_url;
```

Works great at echoing the list.  What I would like to do instead of echoing the information could I possibly take the links and download the image files?

Or instead of echoing save the names to a one big file list?

I have been trying all sorts of of stuff for the past 2 days.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I have been trying all sorts of of stuff for the past 2 days." -- well, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to try something.  If you want to download the url you can use `file_put_contents('image_name', file_get_contents($user->photo_url))`

or you can open up a file and write all the names to it.  Just typing "writing to file in php" will give you php documentation on `file_put_contents` and `fopen`.  One can use `fopen` to open a file for ewriting and write to that file using  [`fwrite`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Comment: since there are over a 100 files, how could I do this with the data?  like using a variable?

Comment: You can use a variable as part of the file name. `$image_name = sprintf('image-%03d', $user->id);` should give you a name that starts with `'image-'` and then the user id, zero-padded to be at least three digits.

Comment: Working with dm and Arjan's examples used set a variable name as $user->id. works great thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

This might work: http://psoug.org/snippet/Saving-Remote-Images-With-PHP_938.htm

Comment: This would only do one at a time.  I was hoping to find a solution that would allow me to write a single .  I am new to php and am really struggling.

Comment: @dianeinflorida i dont understand what you are trying to say... are you saying you want to save multiple image files into a single file? because its not possible...

Comment: I want to save all the images into their own files.

Comment: @dianeinflorida call the save_image function from the above link and put it your code, then call save_image($user->photo_url, $new_name) inside your foreach loop

Comment: save_image? is that like imagecreate?

Comment: FUNCTION save_image($img, $fullpath){
 
 $ch = curl_init ($img);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
 $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
 IF(FILE_EXISTS($fullpath)){
  UNLINK($fullpath);
 }
 $fp = FOPEN($fullpath,'x');
 FWRITE($fp, $rawdata);
 FCLOSE($fp);
 
}

Comment: Using that Function would I still have to set all the filenames, etc?

Comment: yeah, the first argument is the remote image url and the second argument is the image path you want on your local file. If you want to save 'remote/abcd.jpeg' on your local server as '1.jpeg', just call => save_image('remote/abcd.jpeg','1.jpeg');

Comment: Since the filenames woudl change monthly I would like to be able to use the received information as filenames

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
foreach($obj as $index => $user) 
    exec("wget $user->photo_url -O $path_to_local_image");
```